# Does Perl module Imager change image colors by default?

Tags: image, perl, image-processing

I have been using the Perl module Imager (available free from cpan.org) and have had almost entirely good results.  Today however, I noticed that one particular image has its colors muted when I open it and save it using the module.  I condensed my example down to just a few lines:

```
use Imager;
use strict;

my ($file) = @ARGV;

my $img = Imager->new(file => $file) or die "Couldn't open $file.\n";
my $png_file = $file;
$png_file = 'd_' . $png_file;
$png_file =~ s/jpg/png/;
$img->write(file => $png_file) or die "Cannot write $png_file: ", Imager->errstr;
```

Notice that I don't perform any manipulation of the image.
I have uploaded the file for which I see the most muting of the colors.  The input file is

[Download petals.jpg from FileFactory.com](http://www.filefactory.com/file/2l3rqss2ls23/n/petals.jpg)

The output file is

[Download d_petals.png from FileFactory.com](http://www.filefactory.com/file/57i93nju3aj5/n/d_petals.png)

As you can see, the colors are duller in the output file.

Originally, I was outputting JPEG files and thought that the compression might be causing the color changes.  But in this example, I use the PNG format, which I believe is free from compression.

Does anyone have any idea why the colors were muted in d_petals.png?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know the exact answer, but it is caused by some metadata in the image. (IPTC?). If you have installed the ImageMagick utilities, you can try the next:

```
convert petals.jpg petals2.jpg
```

show, and the images are the same. (at least looks like identical)

Now, try the next command:

```
convert -strip petals.jpg petals_strip.jpg
```

the `-strip` strips the metadata from the image.

show, and the `petals_strip.jpg` looks differently and the only thing what is changed is the metadata.

The same is when you `convert` to `png`.

```
convert petals.jpg petals2.png
convert -strip petals.jpg petals_strip.png
```

again the `petals2.png` and `petals_strip.png` are looks different.

Lastly, only `-strip` metadata from the converted `petals2.png`

```
convert -strip petals2.png p2.png
```

and again, they're different.

The image saved by the `Imager` looks like the *stripped* images, from the ImageMagick. Therefore, IMHO the different look is caused by some (missing) metadata from the image created by the Imager.

The metadata from the "petals.jpg:

```
$ exiftool petals.jpg 
ExifTool Version Number         : 9.54
File Name                       : petals.jpg
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 2016 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2014:08:04 00:11:23+02:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2014:08:05 18:48:07+02:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2014:08:05 18:48:33+02:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : JPEG
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
Exif Byte Order                 : Little-endian (Intel, II)
Photometric Interpretation      : RGB
Make                            : NIKON CORPORATION
Camera Model Name               : NIKON D7000
Orientation                     : Horizontal (normal)
Samples Per Pixel               : 3
X Resolution                    : 289.882
Y Resolution                    : 289.882
Resolution Unit                 : inches
Software                        : Adobe Photoshop CS6 (Windows)
Modify Date                     : 2014:08:03 17:40:44
Copyright                       : 
White Balance                   : Auto
Exposure Time                   : 1/250
F Number                        : 8.0
Exposure Program                : Manual
ISO                             : 640
Exif Version                    : 0230
Date/Time Original              : 2013:09:16 23:23:58
Create Date                     : 2013:09:16 23:23:58
Components Configuration        : Y, Cb, Cr, -
Compressed Bits Per Pixel       : 2
Shutter Speed Value             : 1/250
Aperture Value                  : 8.0
Exposure Compensation           : 0
Max Aperture Value              : 1.7
Metering Mode                   : Spot
Light Source                    : Unknown
Flash                           : On, Return detected
Focal Length                    : 50.0 mm
User Comment                    : 
Sub Sec Time                    : 70
Sub Sec Time Original           : 70
Sub Sec Time Digitized          : 70
Flashpix Version                : 0100
Color Space                     : Uncalibrated
Exif Image Width                : 1960
Exif Image Height               : 1764
Sensing Method                  : One-chip color area
File Source                     : Digital Camera
Custom Rendered                 : Normal
Exposure Mode                   : Manual
Digital Zoom Ratio              : 1
Focal Length In 35mm Format     : 75 mm
Scene Capture Type              : Standard
Gain Control                    : Low gain up
Contrast                        : Normal
Saturation                      : Normal
Sharpness                       : Normal
Subject Distance Range          : Unknown
Compression                     : JPEG (old-style)
Thumbnail Offset                : 1218
Thumbnail Length                : 7234
Current IPTC Digest             : 0d5e4e26c030f6f0fc7d7bdc2121db4b
Coded Character Set             : UTF8
Application Record Version      : 0
Time Created                    : 23:23:58+00:00
Copyright Notice                : 
IPTC Digest                     : 0d5e4e26c030f6f0fc7d7bdc2121db4b
Displayed Units X               : inches
Displayed Units Y               : inches
Global Angle                    : 30
Global Altitude                 : 30
Photoshop Thumbnail             : (Binary data 7234 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Photoshop Quality               : 12
Photoshop Format                : Standard
Progressive Scans               : 3 Scans
XMP Toolkit                     : Adobe XMP Core 5.3-c011 66.145661, 2012/02/06-14:56:27
Creator Tool                    : Adobe Photoshop CS5.1 Windows
Metadata Date                   : 2014:08:03 17:40:44-04:00
Date Created                    : 2013:09:16 23:23:58.007
Legacy IPTC Digest              : 89B13B48B88AF1DCBAD4206D7A660031
Color Mode                      : RGB
ICC Profile Name                : Adobe RGB (1998)
Document ID                     : 81871ED35248453A644438627ACF0910
Instance ID                     : xmp.iid:00CC12F6551BE4119728F2BBC7B38EEA
Original Document ID            : 81871ED35248453A644438627ACF0910
Format                          : image/jpeg
History Action                  : saved, saved
History Instance ID             : xmp.iid:A34006F71CD5E311962298F5516CF143, xmp.iid:00CC12F6551BE4119728F2BBC7B38EEA
History When                    : 2014:05:06 08:52:03-04:00, 2014:08:03 17:40:44-04:00
History Software Agent          : Adobe Photoshop CS6 (Windows), Adobe Photoshop CS6 (Windows)
History Changed                 : /, /
Rights                          : 
Creator                         : 
Profile CMM Type                : ADBE
Profile Version                 : 2.1.0
Profile Class                   : Display Device Profile
Color Space Data                : RGB
Profile Connection Space        : XYZ
Profile Date Time               : 2000:08:11 19:51:59
Profile File Signature          : acsp
Primary Platform                : Apple Computer Inc.
CMM Flags                       : Not Embedded, Independent
Device Manufacturer             : none
Device Model                    : 
Device Attributes               : Reflective, Glossy, Positive, Color
Rendering Intent                : Perceptual
Connection Space Illuminant     : 0.9642 1 0.82491
Profile Creator                 : ADBE
Profile ID                      : 0
Profile Copyright               : Copyright 2000 Adobe Systems Incorporated
Profile Description             : Adobe RGB (1998)
Media White Point               : 0.95045 1 1.08905
Media Black Point               : 0 0 0
Red Tone Reproduction Curve     : (Binary data 14 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Green Tone Reproduction Curve   : (Binary data 14 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Blue Tone Reproduction Curve    : (Binary data 14 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Red Matrix Column               : 0.60974 0.31111 0.01947
Green Matrix Column             : 0.20528 0.62567 0.06087
Blue Matrix Column              : 0.14919 0.06322 0.74457
DCT Encode Version              : 100
APP14 Flags 0                   : [14]
APP14 Flags 1                   : (none)
Color Transform                 : YCbCr
Image Width                     : 1960
Image Height                    : 1764
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:4:4 (1 1)
Aperture                        : 8.0
Date/Time Created               : 2013:09:16 23:23:58+00:00
Image Size                      : 1960x1764
Scale Factor To 35 mm Equivalent: 1.5
Shutter Speed                   : 1/250
Create Date                     : 2013:09:16 23:23:58.70
Date/Time Original              : 2013:09:16 23:23:58.70
Modify Date                     : 2014:08:03 17:40:44.70
Thumbnail Image                 : (Binary data 7234 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Circle Of Confusion             : 0.020 mm
Field Of View                   : 27.0 deg
Focal Length                    : 50.0 mm (35 mm equivalent: 75.0 mm)
Hyperfocal Distance             : 15.60 m
Light Value                     : 11.3
```

the metadata from the "stripped" after the `convert -strip petals.jpg petals_stripped.jpg`. These are not real metadata, but the exiftool gathered them from file name/type and such.

```
$ exiftool petals_stripped.jpg 
ExifTool Version Number         : 9.54
File Name                       : petals_stripped.jpg
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 2021 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2014:08:05 18:49:07+02:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2014:08:05 18:49:08+02:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2014:08:05 18:49:07+02:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : JPEG
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
JFIF Version                    : 1.01
Resolution Unit                 : inches
X Resolution                    : 290
Y Resolution                    : 290
Image Width                     : 1960
Image Height                    : 1764
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:4:4 (1 1)
Image Size                      : 1960x1764
```

The stripped image is here, it looks like the image from the `Imager` module. Unfortunately i'm not plays enough to discover what metadata causes the effect.

[image]

Comment: The key phrases to search for are "colour space" and "colour profile" (or "color space" and "color profile" if American). You can inspect this sort of thing in any decent image editor.

Comment: jm666, thanks for your answer.  I looked into the metadata of my image.  I find that the IPTC data in particular contains fields for things like "Creator", "Creator's Job Title", "Address", etc.  Other metadata categories deal with "Document Title", "Author", etc.  I just don't see how any of these address the way RGB values are mapped.

Comment: @Jorocco updated the metadata from your image and uploaded the "stripped" one.

Comment: I received a reply from a maintainer of the module:  "The source image uses the AdobeRGB colour profile, unfortunately
Imager has no colour profile support, so the same colour values are
written out to the PNG with no colour profile set, and the display
software (browser or not) probably defaults to sRGB, which has a
smaller colour range than AdobeRGB."  So now I am trying to figure out if there is some workaround.  I don't see that Imager has a feature to saturate the colors to compensate.  Perhaps there is another Perl image manipulation module that someone can recommend?

Comment: @Jorocco Use https://metacpan.org/pod/Image::Magick. It is bit hairy and the doccu is not the best, but it is the perl interface to ImageMagick what is an GREAT sw. Or alternative: http://www.graphicsmagick.org/perl.html

Comment: jm666, yeah I had about decided that Image::Magick was the way to go, but I'm trying to do things on a Mickeysoft computer, and Image::Magick won't install.  That's a topic for another posting though, and I'm not sure I want to go down that rabbit hole.